# What is the Definition of Thread CPU Time?

Tags: java, multithreading, time, cpu

How do we define "thread CPU Time" for a non-native thread?  More specifically, how is it defined on the JVM (where CPU is abstracted, presumeably, from the JVM, so the definition may be slightly different than for a lower level process)....

I'm working from the JVM implementation of this measurement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html which seems not to directly define what "Thread CPU time" is a direct measurement of.

Comment: For starters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time

Comment: Realistically, what *could* it be other than the amount of CPU time consumed by the given thread? I am not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking in terms of non-native threads. Calculating CPU time for non-native threads may be difficult since the JVM (any process, in general) does not know when it gets CPU time (it can know how many it gets, but then it would not be able to compute which threads used it). But for native threads the OS provides that information.

Comment: Thread cpu time is the amount of time (user + sys) spent by a given thread (on all cpus). And according to the hotspot source, Solaris is an exception, only user time is measured there.

Comment: Yes this is a good point.  Its a very obvious definition in a real CPU but in a non-native thread its non obvious.  I've updated the question accordingly above.

Answer (score 1):

Thread CPU Time is already a pretty generic term. Basically it stands for the amount of time the CPU spent on the given Thread.

It isn't defined any differently because it is on the JVM, the only important part to consider is whether the JVM actually lets you measure it. Some do and some don't.

Comment: yes, but the question is - what is time spent?  What if a thread owns the CPU but isn't doing anything with it?

Comment: time spent is any time given by the CPU to the thread. Whether the thread does "useful" work or not is irrelevant. Spin in a while loop or compute the first N primes, it is still time that can't be given to any other process.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful - i guess my "real" question might actually be "HOW" a java program could ever know how much time the real CPU is giving it.

Answer (score 1):

One doesn't necessarily have to break the abstraction. POSIX does specify a way to measure cpu time per thread. And then there's Windows :)

Searching through the hotspot source, I see:

**hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/os.hpp**

```
  // JVMTI & JVM monitoring and management support
  // The thread_cpu_time() and current_thread_cpu_time() are only
  // supported if is_thread_cpu_time_supported() returns true.
  // They are not supported on Solaris T1.
```

In **hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp** I do see **pthread_getcpuclockid** along with **clock_gettime** being used for this purpose

In **hotspot/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp**, I see **GetThreadTimes** is used.